# Having trouble with AutoSizing between 3.5" and 4" size screens

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, autosize

I am having a bit of trouble with the Autosizing of a UIScrollView within my nib file. It resizes fine in the Inspector view but when it comes on the device the one on the 3.5" version takes the height of the 4" version.

As you can see with the images below it resizes correctly in the interface builder view but on the device the view frame is too long for the 3.5" device.

I can change the frame of the view in the code using absolute values but i'd rather try and get it working by it automatically resizing.

[image]
[image]

Comment: From my experience its better to have your views in .xib files in 3.5" and then let it auto-expand

Comment: Would you please add `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));` to viewDidLoad of the viewController and show what it says for 4" and 3.5"?

Answer (score 0):

It could be problem with UIWindow. Go to UIWindow properties and check that you have enabled **Full screen at Launch**

[image: UIWindow properties]

Answer (score -1):

Your project should be for iOS 6 or higher, where you can use autolayout. That will do the resizing automatically like this. If you don't then you have to do it from code.

Last case: If your project is iOS 6 or higher and don't have autolayout, then on the nib file you're editing click on file's owner, on the Utilities section on the right click on the file inspector button and under the column Interface Builder Document there's a checkbox for "Use Autolayout" that should be checked.

Comment: The app needs to be iOS 5+. Surely the autosizing should work, this is what the anchor points like this were made for.

Comment: There was a feature for this long before autolayout, which is what he is using.  In fact, sometimes I use the older version just because autolayout can be a huge pain at times.